# Can answers on about GPO alterations to User Groups Be Merged?

Tags: support

Due to confusion of the answer given by Joe in the question below and the addition of my picture and information, can the answers be merged together for fellow users looking for the answer to this question?

Question: [How to allow users to login remotely when already granted right through GPO](https://serverfault.com/questions/840260/how-to-allow-users-to-login-remotely-when-already-granted-right-through-gpo/840270?noredirect=1#comment1075085_840270)

Answer (score 1):

You can always [suggest an edit](https://serverfault.com/help/editing) to an existing answer. The suggestion can be approved (or rejected) by the original author or by the community.